# Running multiple commands in Python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, anaconda, subprocess, popen

I have a Python script which I run via Anaconda Prompt.  To run this I go open Anaconda Prompt and run the following commands in order...

```
activate environment1
S:
cd New Project\\Scripts
pythonprocessor.py --file_path "S:\New Project\Data\File 1.txt" --config_path config.ini
```

I need to run this automatically so I'm setting up another Python script that I can use to call these commands.  I'm trying to use subprocess.Popen to do so.  Here's the code...

```
import subprocess

cmds = "activate environment1; S:; cd New Project\\Scripts; pythonprocessor.py --file_path S:\\New Project\\Data\\File 1.txt"
subprocess.Popen(['start','cmd','/k',cmds], shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, text = True)
```

When I run the code I get this exception...

```
ArgumentError: activate does not accept more than one argument:
['environment1;', 'S:;', 'cd', 'New', 'Project\\Scripts;', 'pythonprocessor.py', '--file_path', 'S:\\New', 'Project\\Data\\File', '1.txt']
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Semicolons aren't a command separator in Windows CMD; you're running a single, huge, nonsensical command.  Use `&` instead, or `&&` if you want to stop if one of the commands fails.